# PHP работа со строками URL

Tags: php, url, get

Здравствуйте допустим есть страница:
 https://mysite/profile#access_token=32f4539aeec6311e0d06f2305aeee88fbd9bfc773f885980c40a195672d1fa9247a6177c1746b67c4c779

После авторизации, юзер возвращается на сайт, сервис авторизации приписывает токен в ссылку урла, как с нее его достать, тоесть значение access_token, get не работает, пустой

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php). - ваши данные будут находится по ключу `fragment`.

Comment: Вопрос оформлен не правильно, не с теми метками и вообще работа не со строками а с адресной строкой. Оформите вопрос правильно и возможно вам помогут. А так, тут нужно просто `js`ом перехватывать. А так, вроде и обычный `GET` для этого можно использовать., а не якоря напрочь выжитые.